# Combining columns based on partial column name

Tags: r, concatenation

I was hoping there would be an easier/faster/cleaner way of doing what I want because right now this is super convoluted:

I have column names of :

```
"OTS_SM0_1","OTS_SM0_2","OTS_SM0_3","OTS_SM0_4","OTS_SM0_5","OTS_SM0_6",
"OTS_SM0_7","OTS_SM0_8","OTS_SM0_9",
"OTS_SM1_x1_4","OTS_SM1_x1_6","OTS_SM1_x1_7","OTS_SM1_x1_8",
"OTS_SM1_x2_4","OTS_SM1_x2_6","OTS_SM1_x2_7","OTS_SM1_x2_8",
"OTS_SM1_x3_4","OTS_SM1_x3_6","OTS_SM1_x3_7","OTS_SM1_x3_8",
"OTS_SM1_x4_4","OTS_SM1_x4_6","OTS_SM1_x4_7","OTS_SM1_x4_8",
"OTS_SM1_x5_4","OTS_SM1_x5_6","OTS_SM1_x5_7","OTS_SM1_x5_8",
"OTS_SM1_x6_4","OTS_SM1_x6_6","OTS_SM1_x6_7","OTS_SM1_x6_8",
"OTS_SM1_x7_4","OTS_SM1_x7_6","OTS_SM1_x7_7","OTS_SM1_x7_8",
"OTS_SM1_x8_4","OTS_SM1_x8_6","OTS_SM1_x8_7","OTS_SM1_x8_8",
"OTS_SM1_x9_4","OTS_SM1_x9_6","OTS_SM1_x9_7","OTS_SM1_x9_8",
"OTS_SM2_x1","OTS_SM2_x2","OTS_SM2_x3","OTS_SM2_x4","OTS_SM2_x5",
"OTS_SM2_x6","OTS_SM2_x7","OTS_SM2_x8","OTS_SM2_x9"
```

And I need to concatenate their entries into one column based on name. These are the desired names to combine to:

```
OTS_SM0 OTS_SM1_x1  OTS_SM1_x2  OTS_SM1_x3  OTS_SM1_x4  OTS_SM1_x5  OTS_SM1_x6  
OTS_SM1_x7  OTS_SM1_x8  OTS_SM1_x9  OTS_SM2_x1  OTS_SM2_x2  OTS_SM2_x3  OTS_SM2_x4  
OTS_SM2_x5  OTS_SM2_x6  OTS_SM2_x7  OTS_SM2_x8  OTS_SM2_x9
```

However the catch is that these names will not always be the same only the OTS_SM part will remain constant and the number of columns to combine will change as well as their indices within the data frame.

My current solution is:

```
columnnames <- c("OTS_SM0_1","OTS_SM0_2","OTS_SM0_3","OTS_SM0_4","OTS_SM0_5","OTS_SM0_6","OTS_SM0_7","OTS_SM0_8","OTS_SM0_9",
"OTS_SM1_x1_4","OTS_SM1_x1_6","OTS_SM1_x1_7","OTS_SM1_x1_8","OTS_SM1_x2_4","OTS_SM1_x2_6","OTS_SM1_x2_7","OTS_SM1_x2_8","OTS_SM1_x3_4",
"OTS_SM1_x3_6","OTS_SM1_x3_7","OTS_SM1_x3_8","OTS_SM1_x4_4","OTS_SM1_x4_6","OTS_SM1_x4_7","OTS_SM1_x4_8","OTS_SM1_x5_4","OTS_SM1_x5_6",
"OTS_SM1_x5_7","OTS_SM1_x5_8","OTS_SM1_x6_4","OTS_SM1_x6_6","OTS_SM1_x6_7","OTS_SM1_x6_8","OTS_SM1_x7_4","OTS_SM1_x7_6","OTS_SM1_x7_7",
"OTS_SM1_x7_8","OTS_SM1_x8_4","OTS_SM1_x8_6","OTS_SM1_x8_7","OTS_SM1_x8_8","OTS_SM1_x9_4","OTS_SM1_x9_6","OTS_SM1_x9_7","OTS_SM1_x9_8",
"OTS_SM2_x1","OTS_SM2_x2","OTS_SM2_x3","OTS_SM2_x4","OTS_SM2_x5","OTS_SM2_x6","OTS_SM2_x7","OTS_SM2_x8","OTS_SM2_x9")

names1_index = grep('^(?!.*x).*OTS_SM', columnnames, perl=TRUE)
names1 = columnnames[names1_index]
names1 = substring(names1, 1, 7)
names2_index = grep("OTS_SM.*_x", columnnames)
names2 = columnnames[names2_index]
names2 = substring(names2, 1, 10)
```

which gives the output like this:

```
> names1
"OTS_SM0" "OTS_SM0" "OTS_SM0" "OTS_SM0" "OTS_SM0" 
"OTS_SM0" "OTS_SM0" "OTS_SM0" "OTS_SM0"
> names2
"OTS_SM1_x1" "OTS_SM1_x1" "OTS_SM1_x1" "OTS_SM1_x1" "OTS_SM1_x2" 
"OTS_SM1_x2" "OTS_SM1_x2" "OTS_SM1_x2" "OTS_SM1_x3" "OTS_SM1_x3" 
"OTS_SM1_x3" "OTS_SM1_x3" "OTS_SM1_x4" "OTS_SM1_x4" "OTS_SM1_x4" 
"OTS_SM1_x4" "OTS_SM1_x5" "OTS_SM1_x5" "OTS_SM1_x5" "OTS_SM1_x5" 
"OTS_SM1_x6" "OTS_SM1_x6" "OTS_SM1_x6" "OTS_SM1_x6" "OTS_SM1_x7" 
"OTS_SM1_x7" "OTS_SM1_x7" "OTS_SM1_x7" "OTS_SM1_x8" "OTS_SM1_x8"
"OTS_SM1_x8" "OTS_SM1_x8" "OTS_SM1_x9" "OTS_SM1_x9" "OTS_SM1_x9"
"OTS_SM1_x9" "OTS_SM2_x1" "OTS_SM2_x2" "OTS_SM2_x3" "OTS_SM2_x4" 
"OTS_SM2_x5" "OTS_SM2_x6" "OTS_SM2_x7" "OTS_SM2_x8" "OTS_SM2_x9"
```

So for example for the `name1` variable in the dataframe DF:

```
   OTS_SM0_1 OTS_SM0_2 OTS_SM0_3 OTS_SM0_4 OTS_SM0_5 OTS_SM0_6 OTS_SM0_7 OTS_SM0_8 OTS_SM0_9        
   <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>            
 1 0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         None of the above
 2 Facebook  0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0                
 3 0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         None of the above
 4 Facebook  Instagram Twitter   Snapchat  Pinterest 0         Tik Tok   0         0                
 5 0         0         0         0         0         LinkedIn  0         0         0                
 6 Facebook  0         0         0         Pinterest 0         0         0         0                
 7 Facebook  Instagram 0         0         0         0         0         0         0                
 8 Facebook  Instagram 0         0         Pinterest 0         Tik Tok   0         0                
 9 NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA               
10 NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
```

I would then combine same name column indices:

```
unique_names1 <- unique(names1)
for (i in 1:length(unique_names1)){
  combine1= DF[,grep(unique_names1[i],colnames(DF))]
  NewCol1 <- do.call(paste, c(combine1[], sep = ";"))
  NewCol1 <- str_remove_all(NewCol1,";NA")
  NewCol1 <- str_remove_all(NewCol1,"NA;")
  NewCol1 <- str_remove_all(NewCol1,";0")
  NewCol1 <- str_remove_all(NewCol1,"0;")
  DF <- cbind(DF,NewCol1)
}
```

```
NewCol1
   [1] "None of the above"        "Facebook"                                                             
   [3] "None of the above"        "Facebook;Instagram;Twitter;Snapchat;Pinterest;Tik Tok"
   [5] "LinkedIn"                 "Facebook;Pinterest"                                         
   [7] "Facebook;Instagram"       "Facebook;Instagram;Pinterest;Tik Tok"                        
   [9] "NA"                       "NA"
```

Which is then obviously renamed to "OTS_SM0" using some more fun indexing. As well as removing the original columns.

Comment: It is easier for ppl to help you if you share data with `dput` or wrap your data in `head` and then use that in `dput`. In general, I think you can easily solve this by using `dplyr::pivot_long` -> `dplyr::separate` -> `dplyr::pivot_wider`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your dataframe `DF` looks like this

```
  OTS_SM0_1 OTS_SM0_2 OTS_SM0_3 OTS_SM0_4 OTS_SM0_5 OTS_SM0_6 OTS_SM0_7 OTS_SM0_8 OTS_SM0_9 OTS_SM1_x1_4 OTS_SM1_x1_6 OTS_SM1_x1_7 OTS_SM1_x1_8 OTS_SM1_x2_4 OTS_SM1_x2_6 OTS_SM1_x2_7 OTS_SM1_x2_8 OTS_SM1_x3_4 OTS_SM1_x3_6 OTS_SM1_x3_7 OTS_SM1_x3_8 OTS_SM1_x4_4 OTS_SM1_x4_6 OTS_SM1_x4_7 OTS_SM1_x4_8 OTS_SM1_x5_4 OTS_SM1_x5_6 OTS_SM1_x5_7 OTS_SM1_x5_8 OTS_SM1_x6_4 OTS_SM1_x6_6 OTS_SM1_x6_7 OTS_SM1_x6_8 OTS_SM1_x7_4 OTS_SM1_x7_6 OTS_SM1_x7_7 OTS_SM1_x7_8 OTS_SM1_x8_4 OTS_SM1_x8_6 OTS_SM1_x8_7 OTS_SM1_x8_8 OTS_SM1_x9_4 OTS_SM1_x9_6 OTS_SM1_x9_7 OTS_SM1_x9_8 OTS_SM2_x1 OTS_SM2_x2 OTS_SM2_x3 OTS_SM2_x4 OTS_SM2_x5 OTS_SM2_x6 OTS_SM2_x7 OTS_SM2_x8 OTS_SM2_x9
1         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9           10           11           12           13           14           15           16           17           18           19           20           21           22           23           24           25           26           27           28           29           30           31           32           33           34           35           36           37           38           39           40           41           42           43           44           45         46         47         48         49         50         51         52         53         54
2         2         4         6         8        10        12        14        16        18           20           22           24           26           28           30           32           34           36           38           40           42           44           46           48           50           52           54           56           58           60           62           64           66           68           70           72           74           76           78           80           82           84           86           88           90         92         94         96         98        100        102        104        106        108
```

Here is a `dplyr` approach. We use `id` to preserve row relationships. After the first pivot, we remove the characters followed by the last `"_"` only if they are digits. Last, we summarize the rows into a single cell for each group of id and variable (`name` in this case) and convert the dataframe from long to wide.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-id) %>%
  group_by(id, name = sub("(_\\d+)?$", "", name)) %>%
  summarize(value = paste0(value, collapse = ";"), .groups = "drop") %>%
  pivot_wider() %>%
  select(-id)
```

Output (I used a different print method to show you all the columns. The default print method may render something different on your screen, but the underlying object is the same.)

```
                 OTS_SM0  OTS_SM1_x1  OTS_SM1_x2  OTS_SM1_x3  OTS_SM1_x4  OTS_SM1_x5  OTS_SM1_x6  OTS_SM1_x7  OTS_SM1_x8  OTS_SM1_x9 OTS_SM2_x1 OTS_SM2_x2 OTS_SM2_x3 OTS_SM2_x4 OTS_SM2_x5 OTS_SM2_x6 OTS_SM2_x7 OTS_SM2_x8 OTS_SM2_x9
1      1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9 10;11;12;13 14;15;16;17 18;19;20;21 22;23;24;25 26;27;28;29 30;31;32;33 34;35;36;37 38;39;40;41 42;43;44;45         46         47         48         49         50         51         52         53         54
2 2;4;6;8;10;12;14;16;18 20;22;24;26 28;30;32;34 36;38;40;42 44;46;48;50 52;54;56;58 60;62;64;66 68;70;72;74 76;78;80;82 84;86;88;90         92         94         96         98        100        102        104        106        108
```

---

However, if you want to do some analysis of the variables, having values nested in a single cell is usually not helpful. Perhaps you would also like to consider a slightly different representation of the data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF %>%
  rename_with(~sub("(_\\d+)?$", "`\\1", .)) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-id, names_to = c(".value", NA), names_pattern = "(.+)`(_\\d+)?")
```

, which gives

```
   id OTS_SM0 OTS_SM1_x1 OTS_SM1_x2 OTS_SM1_x3 OTS_SM1_x4 OTS_SM1_x5 OTS_SM1_x6 OTS_SM1_x7 OTS_SM1_x8 OTS_SM1_x9 OTS_SM2_x1 OTS_SM2_x2 OTS_SM2_x3 OTS_SM2_x4 OTS_SM2_x5 OTS_SM2_x6 OTS_SM2_x7 OTS_SM2_x8 OTS_SM2_x9
1   1       1         10         14         18         22         26         30         34         38         42         46         47         48         49         50         51         52         53         54
2   1       2         11         15         19         23         27         31         35         39         43         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
3   1       3         12         16         20         24         28         32         36         40         44         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
4   1       4         13         17         21         25         29         33         37         41         45         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
5   1       5         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
6   1       6         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
7   1       7         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
8   1       8         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
9   1       9         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
10  2       2         20         28         36         44         52         60         68         76         84         92         94         96         98        100        102        104        106        108
11  2       4         22         30         38         46         54         62         70         78         86         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
12  2       6         24         32         40         48         56         64         72         80         88         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
13  2       8         26         34         42         50         58         66         74         82         90         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
14  2      10         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
15  2      12         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
16  2      14         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
17  2      16         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
18  2      18         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
```

---

Data

```
structure(list(OTS_SM0_1 = c(1, 2), OTS_SM0_2 = c(2, 4), OTS_SM0_3 = c(3, 
6), OTS_SM0_4 = c(4, 8), OTS_SM0_5 = c(5, 10), OTS_SM0_6 = c(6, 
12), OTS_SM0_7 = c(7, 14), OTS_SM0_8 = c(8, 16), OTS_SM0_9 = c(9, 
18), OTS_SM1_x1_4 = c(10, 20), OTS_SM1_x1_6 = c(11, 22), OTS_SM1_x1_7 = c(12, 
24), OTS_SM1_x1_8 = c(13, 26), OTS_SM1_x2_4 = c(14, 28), OTS_SM1_x2_6 = c(15, 
30), OTS_SM1_x2_7 = c(16, 32), OTS_SM1_x2_8 = c(17, 34), OTS_SM1_x3_4 = c(18, 
36), OTS_SM1_x3_6 = c(19, 38), OTS_SM1_x3_7 = c(20, 40), OTS_SM1_x3_8 = c(21, 
42), OTS_SM1_x4_4 = c(22, 44), OTS_SM1_x4_6 = c(23, 46), OTS_SM1_x4_7 = c(24, 
48), OTS_SM1_x4_8 = c(25, 50), OTS_SM1_x5_4 = c(26, 52), OTS_SM1_x5_6 = c(27, 
54), OTS_SM1_x5_7 = c(28, 56), OTS_SM1_x5_8 = c(29, 58), OTS_SM1_x6_4 = c(30, 
60), OTS_SM1_x6_6 = c(31, 62), OTS_SM1_x6_7 = c(32, 64), OTS_SM1_x6_8 = c(33, 
66), OTS_SM1_x7_4 = c(34, 68), OTS_SM1_x7_6 = c(35, 70), OTS_SM1_x7_7 = c(36, 
72), OTS_SM1_x7_8 = c(37, 74), OTS_SM1_x8_4 = c(38, 76), OTS_SM1_x8_6 = c(39, 
78), OTS_SM1_x8_7 = c(40, 80), OTS_SM1_x8_8 = c(41, 82), OTS_SM1_x9_4 = c(42, 
84), OTS_SM1_x9_6 = c(43, 86), OTS_SM1_x9_7 = c(44, 88), OTS_SM1_x9_8 = c(45, 
90), OTS_SM2_x1 = c(46, 92), OTS_SM2_x2 = c(47, 94), OTS_SM2_x3 = c(48, 
96), OTS_SM2_x4 = c(49, 98), OTS_SM2_x5 = c(50, 100), OTS_SM2_x6 = c(51, 
102), OTS_SM2_x7 = c(52, 104), OTS_SM2_x8 = c(53, 106), OTS_SM2_x9 = c(54, 
108)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `iris` dataset is a good approximation of your problem:

```
head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

We can do this pretty easily in tidyverse. First we convert to long-form so the names are easy to work with. Then, we truncate the names to the core you want to use for the combined columns. Then we spread it back to wide form with the new, more limited number of columns.

There's one other step needed: `pivot_wider` ensures each row is unique, so the new "Sepal" and "Petal" columns each contain a list of the values for each Species. Since you one one row for each (you're just concatinating), we use `unnest` to take those list columns and convert them into multiple rows:

```
library(tidyverse)
iris %>%
    pivot_longer(-Species) %>%
    mutate(name = gsub('\\..*', '', name)) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = 'name', values_from = 'value', values_fn = list) %>%
    unnest(cols = c('Sepal', 'Petal'))

# A tibble: 300 × 3
   Species Sepal Petal
   <fct>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1 setosa    5.1   1.4
 2 setosa    3.5   0.2
 3 setosa    4.9   1.4
 4 setosa    3     0.2
 5 setosa    4.7   1.3
 6 setosa    3.2   0.2
 7 setosa    4.6   1.5
 8 setosa    3.1   0.2
 9 setosa    5     1.4
10 setosa    3.6   0.2
# … with 290 more rows
```

If you really don't want to have to specify the column names in `unnest` you can use `unnest(cols = colnames(.))` to apply it to all, or just leave out the `cols` argument (though that will give a warning and might break in the future),

Comment: I think this could work but the thing with truncating the names is that OTS_SM0_1 and OTS_SM0_2 need to be combined but OTS_SM1_x1 OTS_SM1_x2 arent. So truncating to OTS_SM# would combine the wrong columns.

Comment: @megmac You just need to find the right way to truncate them. It seems like you just want to chop off the last underscore number. So the regex:  `_[0-9]$` would do that